# Autopan issue occuring in Bing Maps AJAX upon resizing a map?

Tags: bing-maps

Am working on a project where we have a Bing map being resized depending on whether or not a panel is shown/hidden on the left-hand side of the map. Because of this, and Microsoft's terms preventing overlaying anything over the logo/copyright, etc, I'm using the VEMap.resize method to resize the map, and then am moving the panel out of the way. The issue is that there's an awkward autopan that occurs as part of the resize - because we're declaring a center point to determine the resize, the map pans to include this point in the center without any control over it. Without declaring a center, the map doesn't pan, but it also doesn't pull the new data (map tiles) in our resize in either, resulting in an awkward grey bar on the right-hand side..

Is there a simple way to either resize the map and disable that autopan, moving the center prior to the panning, or to force the map tiles to be rendered upon the resize itself? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the new version 7.0 as you could get rid of this annoyance by using "map.setView({center: map.getCenter(), animate:false})" after resizing; that should override the nice but annoying pan movement on resize.

However there are a few features (like infoboxes or client-side clustering) currently missing in 7.0 when migrating from 6.3 however and the classnames changed, so you may want to wait for now, however it would be the good moment to prepare yourself for 7.